# Select from all tables with same start

Tags: php, mysql

How to select all tables who whas fs_ for example, its not a prefix, its a something added from me , but some tables has it, and i want to select all of them, not choasing the one by one, but to select all tables who starts with fs_

Comment: That smells like a really bad database design

Comment: You should clear about what are you doing? _Select from tables_ OR _Select table itself_ which have `fs_`

Comment: What does selecting tables *mean*?  Something like storing their names in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$q = $dbc -> ("SELECT COUNT (*) fs_");

$q -> execute();

$count = $q -> rowCount();

echo $count;
```

It is hard to tell what you are asking or what you are trying to achieve!?

From what you have said try that, if not then please elaborate your question in a more clear and concise way.

Answer (score 1):

in your MySQL database you can create an extra column that will contain such value.
ex:

```
ID | NAME | DATE | FS_COLUMN  
1    jon    2011   1  
2    doe    2005   0  
3    tom    2001   1
```

Then with PHP you can fetch these rows.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE FS_COLUMN='1'");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
```

Answer (score 0):

well ... it's really no good design approach but to answer your question:

you will probably want to get all matching tables by

```
SELECT table_name  
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = '___YOUR_DB_NAME___' 
AND table_name LIKE 'fa\_%'
```

and construct your query based on the result